# What does this series with generalized falling factorial converge to?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

I have a series which contains an $nth$ term $t(t-a)(t-2a)(t-3a)...(t-(n-1)a) = f(t,n).$

The series itself is

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f(t,n)e^{-an}}{n!}.$$

I looked at this article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials

and at the bottom of the "Relation to umbral calculus" section, I see a series with a falling factorial that converges to a known result. However, this doesn't quite match what I see.

So, I scroll further down and see under the "Generalizations" section that this object has a name, $f(t,n) = t^{n/-a}.$

Can these results be combined in any way to yield an explicit result? I'm hoping the result is some type of exponential function.

Comment: Note $f(t,n)/n!=a^n{t/a\choose n}$ so you're very close to the binomial theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding Gerry's comment into an answer,
\begin{align}
\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{f(t,n)}{n!}e^{-an}
&=\sum_{n\ge 0} \frac{(t/a)(t/a-1)\cdots (t/a-n+1)}{n!} \cdot a^ n\cdot e^{-an}\\
&=\sum_{n\ge 0} \binom{t/a}{n} \Big(ae^{-a}\Big)^{n}\\
&= (1+ae^{-a})^{t/a}
\end{align}
The last step uses Newton's binomial theorem.

Comment: Good. But I can't help thinking it would have been better to encourage OP to do some of the work.